# Contact Form with Javascript

Tags: javascript, email, win-universal-app, winjs, contact-form

**Hello**,
i'm trying to create a Windows 10 App with Javascript for self education. Today i want to try, send a email with message, Name from a Contact form. I'm only beginner on Javascript. can someone write a short code with example? I have a Contact form with PHP, but how can i send a Mail with Javascript?

```
<form method="post" action="send.js">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name" required=" ">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email" required=" ">
    <textarea placeholder="Message..." name="msg" id="msg" required=" "></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send e-mails via JavaScript, use Node.js Nodemailer.
https://nodemailer.com/[Nodemailer - Send e-mails with Node.JS](https://nodemailer.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use

```
 <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">Send email</a>
```

And that will open the default mail application on the user's device, and automatically fill in the *To:* field with that e-mail address.

[Here is an example of how it works.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_mailto)

It is also possible to specify initial values for headers (e.g. subject, cc, etc.) and message body in the URL. Blanks, carriage returns, and linefeeds cannot be embedded but must be percent-encoded.

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?subject=This%20is%20the%20subject&cc=someone_else@example.com&body=This%20is%20the%20body">Send email</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't send mail with javascript. Normally you'd use javascript to send your form to your php page. You could use something like jquery and ajax the form to you php script so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#your-form-id').on('submit', function(){
        var formData = $(this).serialize
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'your_url.php',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                //Anything you want to do after form is submitted
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This isn't tested code but I think it should be roughly right.